# Should we sanitize file names uploaded to server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

When uploading files to a server. Should the file name be sanitized? i.e. avoiding non-ASCII characters like `é` or `&`?

Or should we allow these files to be saved as is?

PS. In Rails 3, I can't remember the method. It changes non-ascii chars to underscores and etc. Someone remind me pls. It's not `sanitize`. Its a different method.

Comment: If you do want to sanitize then here are some suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756022/php-how-to-sanitize-uploaded-filenames

Comment: Found what I was looking for. It was `transliterate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that you sanitize /, \ and \0 if sent from maliciuos user agents. 
If your filesystem fully supports Unicode, I would save them as they were sent by agent.

My preferred solution: 
Use a unique id as filename and store real filename in an additional file or database. So your application gets portable for systems not supporting Unicode

Comment: And lets say a user decides to download the file. How would I be able to rename this to its original file name before serving it out?

Comment: Look for header 'Content-Disposition'.